# Building a tuple containing colons to be used to index a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've created a class for dealing with multidimensional data of a specific type. This class has three attributes: A list containing the names of the axes (**self.axisNames**); a dictionary containing the parameter values along each axis (**self.axes**; keyd using the entries in axisNames); and a numpy array containing the data, with a dimension for each axis (**self.intensityArr**).

The class also has functions that dynamically add new axes depending on what I need for a specific case, which makes indexing the intensityArr a tricky proposition. To make indexing better I've started writing a function to build the index I need:

Inside class:

```
def indexIntensityArr(self,indexSpec):
    # indexSpec is a dictionary containing axisName:indexVal entries (indexVal is an int)
    # I want the function to return a tuple for use in indexing (see below def)
    indexList = []
    for axis in self.axisNames:
        if axis in indexSpec:
            indexList.append(indexSpec[axis])
        else:
            # <do something to add : to index list (tuple)>
    return tuple(indexList)
```

Outside class:

```
# ... create an instance of my class called myBlob with 4 dimensions ...

mySpec = {'axis1':10,'axis3':7}
mySlicedArr = myBlob.intensityArr[myBlob.indexIntensityArr(mySpec)]
```

I expect the above to result in mySlicedArr being a 2-dimensional array.

What do I need to put in the 'else' clause to get an : (or equivalent) in the tuple I use to index the intensityArr? Is this perhaps a bad way to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question, but if I do, I think that you would probably want to put `indexList = (slice(),)` in the `else` clause.

Comment: I also think you should look into slices. I'm having the impression that you are trying to reinvent numpy's structured arrays or smth like that

Comment: @dnalow this is indeed a use-case which would probably benifit from the use of something like numpy's structured arrays. This code will, however, be passed on to other students and researchers with less experience than myself, so I'm limiting myself to common structures as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside indexing `[]`, a `:` is translated to a `slice`, and the whole thing is passed to `__getitem__` as a tuple

```
indexList = []
for axis in self.axisNames:
    if axis in indexSpec:
        indexList.append(indexSpec[axis])
    else:
        indexList.append(slice(None))
```

There are several `numpy` functions that use an indexing trick like this - that is build up a tuple of index values and slices.  Or if they need to vary it, they'll start with a list, which can mutate, and convert it to a tuple right before use.  (e.g. `np.apply_along_axis`)

Yes, the full spec for slice is `slice(start, stop, step)`, with start and stop optional.  Same as for `np.arange` or `range`.  And `None` is equivalent to the unspecified values in a `:` expression.

A little custom class in `np.lib.index_tricks.py` translates the : notation into slices:

```
In [61]: np.s_[:,:1,0:,::3]
Out[61]: 
(slice(None, None, None),
 slice(None, 1, None),
 slice(0, None, None),
 slice(None, None, 3))
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need! I just want to add what @Praveen said, that you can use `slice(start,end)` for actual slices (in a more complicated `if`, of course), before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

To add to hpaulj's answer, you can very simply extend your setup to make it even more generic by using `np.s_`. The advantage of using this over `slice` is that you can use `numpy`'s slice syntax more easily and transparently. For example:

```
mySpec = {'axis1': np.s_[10:15], 'axis3': np.s_[7:8]}
mySlicedArr = myBlob.intensityArr[myBlob.indexIntensityArr(mySpec)]
```

(Extra info: `np.s_[7:8]` retrieves only the 7th column, but it preserves the dimension, i.e. your sliced array will still be 4D with a shape of 1 in that dimension: very useful for broadcasting).

And if you want to use the same syntax in your function definition as well:

```
indexList = []
for axis in self.axisNames:
    if axis in indexSpec:
        indexList.append(indexSpec[axis])
    else:
        indexList.append(np.s_[:])
return tuple(indexList)
```

All of this can be done equally well with `slice`. You would specify `np.s_[10:15]` as `slice(10, 15)`, and `np.s_[:]` as `slice(None)`, as hpaulj says.

Comment: Thanks for the bonus information. This solution is probably what I'm going to use, since it adds the functionality of passing slices, but @hpaulj's answer more directly answers the question.